# How to boot dd image in QEMU?

Tags: debian, dd, qemu, arm, sheevaplug

I created an image of my Debian Squeeze running on a [Sheevaplug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SheevaPlug) using `dd if=/dev/sda of=plug_SD-karte.img` (`sda` is the SD card plugged into another computer). Now I want to emulate the Sheevaplug. I think the best way is using QEMU. But how do I boot the image?

Some information that may be helpful: https://gist.github.com/1034314

**EDIT:** I would use Ubuntu 11.04 to run QEMU on.

Answer (score 3):

as qemu supports raw disk image format, just do

```
qemu -hda plug_SD-karte.img -m 256
```